# Mailjet HTML and tracking

Tags: 7, emails

As the module devs isn't responding to posts like https://www.drupal.org/node/2032343 & https://www.drupal.org/node/2611824 I'm trying my luck here:

I've got a site sending emails via both rules and simplenews. I've got Mailjet, MailSystem and MimeMail installed. If I choose Mimemail in Mailsystem I can send HTML emails without problems - but even newsletter tests then ends up in spam. Plain text mails sent via Rules and Mailjet from my site is generally not seen as spam by email clients so I'd *really* like to use Mailjet as the mail system to improve delivery rates and get statistics.

**Module versions:**

- core: 7.39
- mailjet 7.x-2.6
- mailsystem 7.x-2.34
- mimemail 7.x-1.0-beta4
- simplenews 7.x-1.1

My Mailjet module configuration isn't showing any errors and the test email confirms that the module is configured correctly.

I however have some issues:

1. when I use the Mailjet class in my MailSystem settings all html get's delivered as plain text.
2. Only number of emails delivered are showing at admin/mailjet/stats even though all tracking options are checked at admin/config/system/mailjet

Any ideas on how to use and track HTML in emails delivered by Mailjet?

Comment: It's harder to help when we don't know your Drupal version.

Comment: Thanks @NoSssweat. I've edited the original question to include module & drupal versions